# RcppArmadillo installation error

Tags: r, software-installation

When I am trying to install the RcppArmadillo Bioconductor library in R, it is giving me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [RcppArmadillo.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/home/nikita/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RcppArmadillo’
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, R 3.2.5 and `g++-5.4`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It can't find gfortran. Is it installed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about biology, but rather about software installation.

Comment: In a way you are right. The issue is that this question is more appropriate here rather than on `stackoverflow` because bioinformaticians are here

Comment: I tried installing `gfortran` with `sudo apt-get install gfortran` but it is already there, so nothing happened.

Comment: Do you have r-base-dev installed? It should get the necessary headers.

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko There is a bioinformatics.se...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302209/building-r-package-getting-error-ld-cannot-find-lgfortran) and the solution was to create a symlink as described by `kevin` there:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 /usr/lib/libgfortran.so
```

Comment: This feels like a dirty hack — better fix your GCC installation.

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 14.04 there is a direct route to installing RcppArmadillo. You could perhaps try the same syntax.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rcpparmadillo
```

Comment: It is giving me `Unable to locate package r-cran-rcpparmadillo`